# store words Instead of line

Tags: java, arrays, split, readfile

```
String line = "";
List<String> fruit = new LinkedList<String>();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {

            //System.out.println(line);
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
              if (word.equals("fruit")) {
                line = br.readLine();
                fruit.add(line);

              }

            }


        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String[] fruitArray = fruit.toArray(new String[0]);
for (String s : fruitArray) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
}
```

my code store line in array

but my problem is i need to store a words in array Separated by a a space 
my text like this :

> fruit apples papaya cherry kiwi
>
> banana

my result is :

> banana

thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

by

```
String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
```